# More Tab - tabbedRenderer (custom list of items in automatited MoreTab)

Tags: xamarin.android, tabs, resources

I am trying to custom More Tab which is created automaticly when you have more than 5 Tabbed.
[MoreTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0vEO.png) and lines on [lines in MoreTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYfnP.png)

**1) Trying to solve name which is on bar for multilang. Firstly I tried to solve it by resources but it didnt work. At least on iOS it is translated automaticly if you have lang code in Info.plist on "CFBundleLocalizations"**

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>nl</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>sv</string>
        <string>it</string>
    </array>
```

But on Android this automatic function didnt work. Try to solve it by Resources but I am not able to "force" overwrite of that name on bar.

**2) I made some stylist of list which is generated after open of "More" tab. On iOS I was able to create TabbedRenderer where I can set color of text and style. But didnt find any similar More..Controller under Android. Any advice how to apply similar attributes for droid?**

```
public class MyTabbedRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
                MoreNavigationController.Delegate = new CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate();
        }
    }
    internal class CustomMoreNavigationControllerDelegate : UINavigationControllerDelegate
    {
        public override void WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
        {
            viewController.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            viewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xff, 0x66, 0xff);

            viewController.View.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0x66, 0x33, 0x66);
            if (viewController.View is UITableView tableView)
            {
                tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
                foreach (var cell in tableView.VisibleCells)
                {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xff, 0xaa, 0xaa);
                    cell.TextLabel.TextColor = cell.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0x1f, 0x15, 0x15);
                    if (cell.ImageView?.Image != null)
                    {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = cell.ImageView.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
                        cell.ImageView.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone had the same issue? thanks for help

Comment: Do you develop on Forms project or shell project ? The more tab only shows with shell project if test on android ,but you create a custom renderer used in forms project which would not work on shell project .

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT <BaseControls:TabbedPage
    x:Class="xxxxx"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <views:Tab1 
       IconImageSource="x" 
       BindingContext="x" />

    <views:Tab2
       IconImageSource="x" 
       BindingContext="x" />

Comment: I add 6 tabs on android , but it does not show the moreTab page  , check the image https://imgur.com/gallery/izx1Q8l